# Workflow for using command line R?

Tags: r, command-line, ide

I am used to using R in RStudio. For a new project, I have to use R on the command line, because the data storage and analysis are only allowed to be on a specific server that I connect to using ssh. This server doesn't have rstudio-server to support remote RStudio sessions.

The project involves an extremely large dataset, and some pre-written code to load/format the data that I have been told to run using "source()" before I do anything else. This takes several minutes to run and load the data each time.

What would a good workflow be for something like this? Editing my code in a .r file, saving, then running it would require taking several minutes to load the data each time. But just running R in an interactive session would make it hard to keep track of what I am doing and repeat things if necessary.

Is there some command-line equivalent to RStudio where you can have an interactive session but be editing/saving a file of your code as you go?

Comment: For RStudio you can launch consol and ssh to your remote servers even if your servers dont use expensive RStudio for servers platform. You can then execute all commands from R Studio directly into the ssh with the default shortcut key. This might allow to continue using R studio, track what you're doing in the R scriot, execute interactively.

Comment: You should investigate using `save()` to save intermediate results, and `load()` to reload them.   Then you can restore results for a retry if a later part turns out not to work.

Comment: @JustGettinStarted that is perfect -- THANK YOU!

Comment: k will convert it to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like JuPyteR might be your friend here.
The R kernel works great.

You can use it on a remote server either with exposing an open port (and setting up JuPyteR  login credentials)
Or via port forwarding over SSH.

It is a lot like an interactive reply, except it holds state.
And you can go back and rerun cells.
(Of course state can be dangerous for reproduceability)

Answer (score 0):

For RStudio you can launch console and ssh to your remote servers even if your servers don't use expensive RStudio for servers platform. You can then execute all commands from R Studio directly into the ssh with the default shortcut key. This might allow to continue using R studio, track what you're doing in the R script, execute interactively.